# How to setup multiple components in angular including login?

Tags: html, angular, api, dom

I am working on an Angular project and stuck on this bug for a very long time. Not able to find anything on the web and couldn't find any solution to it by myself.

Description :

I have an HTML document both with different UI as One is feed and One is Login/Signup. I have arranged this template in my app.component.html . Attaching Code below

```
  <app-pageloader></app-pageloader>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <app-login *ngIf = "router.url == '/login'"></app-login>
  <!-- <router-outlet></router-outlet> -->
  <div *ngIf="router.url != '/login'" class="view-wrapper">

<!-- Container -->
<div id="main-feed" class="container">

    <!-- Content placeholders at page load -->
    <!-- this holds the animated content placeholders that show up before content -->
    <!-- Feed page main wrapper -->
    <div id="activity-feed" class="view-wrap true-dom">
        <div class="columns">
            <!-- Left side column -->
            <div class="column is-3 is-hidden-mobile">
              <app-left-sidebar *ngIf="router.url != '/login'"></app-left-sidebar>
            </div>
            <!-- /Left side column -->
            <!-- Middle column -->
            <div class="column is-6">
              <app-postarea></app-postarea>
              <router-outlet></router-outlet>
              <app-loadmore></app-loadmore>
            </div>
            <!-- /Middle column -->
            <!-- Right side column -->
            <div class="column is-3">
              <app-right-sidebar></app-right-sidebar>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<app-modals></app-modals>

  </div>
```

Now you see my feed template starts from Container and Pageloader and the app header are common in both the interfaces. In my feed template, there are multiple components that only need to load once i.e when we refresh. They are Leftsidebar, Post Area, and Right sidebar and different pages like feed and home are being routed with the help of router outlet.

In the Login Page, there is no need for such things I mentioned above.

Now I want that when I switch to /login. It should only load the login component and No other component should load and when I switch to /feed. All components should load below the container.

I have used the URL approach as of now and will be using accessToken local storage condition to hide and show the component.

This solution is working it is only hiding the component from the main page but it is also loading them in the background making unauthorized API calls.

So now I want that if I switch to /login only the login part should load and if I switch to feed or home or blogs then alongside with router outlet all component should load like sidebars and postarea.So that it only make calls when component is called.

If you have ever come across this problem and solved the problem. Help me too. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the idea is that only logged in users ever get to see anything, you should probably target the `*ngIf` to display only with authenticaed Users like:

`*ngIf="isAuthenticated()"`  or `*ngIf="user && user.id"`

or something along those lines. In fact, it's best to use a [Route Guard](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3) to immediately reroute any non-authenticated users to your login.

Aside from all that, your component is getting activated even before the router.url is a thing. You might try:

```
*ngIf="router.url && router.url!= "" && router.url != '/login'"
```